# Unable to make `solidity-flycheck-solc` and solidity-flycheck-solium-checker-active work

Tags: flycheck

I am unable to make  `solidity-flycheck-solc` work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. `solidity-mode` works where the font color changes. But `flycheck` does not work like it does on python files.

In order to check activated, I typed `uin foo` or change keywords inside my `.sol` file, where there was no warning message generated, or their color changes to `red` or `yellow`.

---

```
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.6.0+commit.26b70077.Darwin.appleclang
$ which solc
/usr/local/bin/solc
```

---

I have following setup in `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'flycheck)
(setq solidity-solc-path "/usr/local/bin/solc") ;; This better be set before requiring solidity mode.
(setq solidity-solium-path "/Users/alper/.npm-packages/bin/solium")
(setq solidity-flycheck-solc-checker-active t)
(setq solidity-flycheck-solium-checker-active t)

(require 'solidity-flycheck)
(require 'solidity-mode)
;; (load "solidity-flycheck")
;(load "solidity-mode")
(setq solidity-comment-style 'slash)
(add-hook 'solidity-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
                 (append '((company-solidity company-capf company-dabbrev-code))
                         company-backends))))
(provide 'init-solidity-mode)

(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

**=>** I removed `solidity-*` files under `~/emacs.d/elpa/`. Then I install through `el-get`, so it installs into `el-get/solidity-mode` where when I try to use `(require ...)` I get an error where it cannot find the file, so I use `(load ...)`.

---

This I what I  get for `M-x` => `flycheck-verify-setup`:

```
Syntax checkers for buffer eBlocBroker.sol in solidity-mode:

  solidity-checker
    - may enable: yes
    - predicate:  t
    - executable: Found at /usr/local/bin/solc


The following syntax checkers are not registered:

  - solium-checker

Try adding these syntax checkers to `flycheck-checkers'.  Flycheck
Mode is disabled.  Use C-u M-x flycheck-disable-checker to enable
disabled checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 31
Emacs version:    26.3
System:           x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Window system:    nil
```

Comment: I think you already read [the configuration  guide](https://github.com/ethereum/emacs-solidity#optional-flycheck-interface) and [that hint in issue 41](https://github.com/ethereum/emacs-solidity/issues/41#issuecomment-508982585). Because, on the first look it seems you got that stuff right. Do you have the `.soliumrc.json` file in your home directory? Does `solium` run on the command line? Did you run `solium --init` as indicated [here](https://solium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#usage)?

Comment: Yes I can run `solium` from the command line. `$ solium -V
Solium version 1.2.5 $ which solium
/Users/alper/.npm-packages/bin//solium` // but solium seems like not hooked

Comment: You wrote: "I removed `solidity-*` files under `/elpha/`". Do you mean `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`? The [emacswiki page for el-get](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/el-get) claims that `el-get` manages initialization and the `load-path` for packages installed by `el-get`. You wrote that you tried to `require` `solidity-mode` and failed. That indicates that something went wrong with the installation. Actually, installing per `package-install` should work out of the box.

Comment: Note that `(load "solidity-flycheck") (load "solidity-mode")` does not fix the `load-path`. In `solidity-flycheck` I found [`(require 'solidity-common)`](https://github.com/ethereum/emacs-solidity/blob/b190993dcb8376e80fb1d9b71f3ed6170bd2a341/solidity-flycheck.el#L31). So without fixing the `load-path` the package will not work. You should make sure that you get a working installation through `package-install` or `el-get`. Otherwise install by hand. But, that also means `(add-to-list 'load-path "YOUR PACKAGE PATH")` at the top of your init stuff for `solidity-mode`!

Comment: BTW. From your info here I vaguely deduce that you are working on Windows Subsystem for Linux. Is that right? Maybe, you could give some system info. Might be related to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for lack of information. I am on Ubuntu(Linux). Yes for `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` in order for a clean installation. Binary paths are correct.

I have opened it as an issue but they close it without a proper solution. (https://github.com/ethereum/emacs-solidity/issues/52). I get lost and I am not sure what is wrong on my end.

Comment: I took a look at issue 52. Thanks for the link. Looks like this is really difficult. One thing I noticed: `(provide 'init-solidity-mode)` does not belong into your init file. I belive you got that by copy-pasting from other peoples init files.

Comment: This is strange: Your `flycheck-verify-setup` says that `solium-checker` is not registered. But, if you load `solidity-flycheck` with `solidity-flycheck-solium-checker-active` set to t then `solium-checker` [is registered](https://github.com/ethereum/emacs-solidity/blob/b190993dcb8376e80fb1d9b71f3ed6170bd2a341/solidity-flycheck.el#L125) in `flycheck-checkers`. Maybe, you should open `solidity-flycheck.el` and run `M-x edebug-defun` on the `(when solidity-flycheck-solium-checker-active ...)` form there. You might notice that something goes wrong there.